# Different results with "same" code

Tags: r

I am asking a simple question. Why are these two code fragments not the same?

```
pNl <- {}

for(i in length(x):length(x)-250) { 
    temp <-x[i] - x[i-1] 
    pNl <-append(pNl, temp, length(pNl))
}

pNl
```

and

```
PnL <- {}

for(i in length(x):(length(x)-250)) {
    temp <- x[i] - x[i-1]
    PnL <- append(PnL, temp, length(PnL))
}


PnL
```

I get different results when I execute them...

I really appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: Please make your question reproducible, i.e. provide us with `x`.

Comment: Obvious error is nonobvious :-) -- this question will no doubt make Mr. Burns happy, as he loves to point out how erroneous code can run w/o errors and produce nothing like what you wanted.

Comment: Operator precedence. (Yet again.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the `for` loop definition. In the first loop statement you have left off brackets, i.e.

```
#length(x):length(x)-250
R> 2:5-1
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

In the second loop you have brackets, so:

```
#length(x):(length(x)-250) 
R> 2:(5-1)
[1] 2 3 4
```

These two statements are not the same and so you are not looping over the same thing.